# How to configure spring mvc project which contains controller both annotated and configured

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, configuration-files

Can any one tell me, how to configure spring mvc project that contains controllers both annotated and configured??

I want to configure static pages using ParametrizedViewController and rest of all using Annotations.

But it is not working??

Please someone tell the configuration file(dispatcher-servlet.xml in my case) which will contain both this requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- Registering MVC stuff necessary for @RequestMapping -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<!-- Your view controller definition -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/home" view-name="home" />
```